# Primefaces Extensions CKEditor not working properly with "rendered" attribute

Tags: jsf, primefaces-extensions, conditional-rendering

I'm trying to build a ui which allows an edit and a none-edit view to the user. Currently it's working, but with a small bug that I don't understand. Could someone explain what exact workflow of JSF rendering and ajax is causing the following:

- When the page is loaded the first time, or reloaded then the "Edit" button which triggers the edit-mode is working perfectly fine.
- As soon as I update the content for the id="currentChapters" section via ajax in the left menu, I have to click the "Edit" button two times in order to get the Editor rendered (doesn't matter what event I user - onclick, oncomplete, or the JSF action). After Once entering the editing view and getting back to the non-editing view, the button works on first click again.
- When I surround only the editor with  tags (not the whole content) and use a navLink as an Edit button, the navLink works perfectly fine. But When I try to save the editor content after entering the edit-mode, the save button now works only on the second click.

I don't get behind the flow of events, that cause this issue.

```
<ui:composition template="../WEB-INF/templates/template-main.xhtml" >
        <ui:define name="title">Projekt</ui:define>
        <ui:define name="content">
            <f:metadata>
                <f:viewAction action="#{ProjectBacking.onPageLoad()}" />
            </f:metadata> 


            <b:row class="projects-page">               
                <b:column span="3" styleClass="project-menu-left">                    
                   <b:accordion rendered="#{Login.user.team.project != null}">
                       <c:forEach items="#{ProjectBacking.projectDocuments}" var="document">
                           <b:panel title="#{document.documentName}">   
                               <b:listLinks>
                                   <c:forEach items="#{document.projectChapters}" var="chapter">
                                       <b:navLink value="#{chapter.chapterOrder}.#{chapter.chapterName}" update="currentChapters">
                                           <f:ajax listener="#{ProjectBacking.setCurrentContentForChapter(chapter)}" 
                                                render="currentChapters"/>
                                       </b:navLink>                                           
                                   </c:forEach>    
                               </b:listLinks>                                                              
                           </b:panel>
                       </c:forEach>                          
                   </b:accordion>                                    
               </b:column> 

                <b:column span="9" id="currentChapters" >    
                    <h:form id="form-ckeditor">
                        <b:row rendered="#{Login.user.team.project != null}">
                        <b:column span="12">
                            <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="user-content-header"> 
                                #{ProjectBacking.currentContent.projectChapter.projectDocument.documentName} - #{ProjectBacking.currentContent.projectChapter.chapterName}
                            </h:panelGroup>
                        </b:column>

                        <b:column span="12">
                            <h:panelGroup layout="block"                                           
                                          styleClass="project-content" 
                                          rendered="#{!ProjectBacking.isEdit}">                                     
                                <h:outputText value="#{ProjectBacking.currentContent.content}" 
                                                escape="false"/>
                            </h:panelGroup>                                
                        </b:column>
                        <b:column span="3"> 
                            <b:commandButton value="Edit" 
                                             look="success" 
                                             rendered="#{!ProjectBacking.isEdit}"  
                                             action="#{ProjectBacking.setIsEditTrue()}"
                                             update="currentChapters"
                                             styleClass="full-width"/>
                        </b:column>
                     <b:column span="12">
                                 <pe:ckEditor id="ckeditor" 
                                            rendered="#{ProjectBacking.isEdit}"
                                            width="100%" 
                                            value="#{ProjectBacking.editorContent}">
                                   <p:ajax event="save"   
                                           listener="#{ProjectBacking.updateProjectContent()}"
                                           update="currentChapters" />
                               </pe:ckEditor>  
                       </b:column>

                   </b:row>
                     </h:form>   
                </b:column>


            </b:row>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
```

Backing bean:

```
@Named("ProjectBacking")
@SessionScoped
public class ProjectsBacking implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    //Field Properties
    private String projectName;
    private ProjectContent currentContent;
    private String editorContent;
    private boolean isEdit;    

    //Data Properties
    private User currentUser;
    private Project project;
    private List<ProjectDocument> projectDocuments;
    private List<ProjectContent> projectContents;


    private String testContent;

    @Inject
    private LoginBacking login;
    @EJB
    private TeamDAO teamDAO;
    @EJB
    private ProjectDAO projectDAO;    
    @EJB 
    private DocumentDAO documentDAO;
    @EJB 
    private ChapterDAO chapterDAO;
    @EJB
    private ProjectDocumentDAO projectDocumentDAO;
    @EJB
    private ProjectChapterDAO projectChapterDAO;
    @EJB
    private ProjectContentDAO projectContentDAO;



    public void onPageLoad() {
       currentUser = login.getUser();
       projectDocuments = projectDocumentDAO.getAllProjectDocumentsOrderedByOrderNumber(); 

       /*
       When Page first time loaded, set the content on the page 
       to the content of the first chapter of the first document 
       (which currently is "Lastenheft")
       */
       if(currentUser.getTeam().getProject()!= null && currentContent == null) {
           currentContent = currentUser.getTeam().getProject().getProjectDocuments().get(0).getProjectChapters().get(0).getProjectContent();
       }
    }

    public void setIsEditTrue() {
        isEdit = true;            
    }

    public String createProject() {
        project = new Project();


        project.setProjectName(projectName);         
        project.setTeam(currentUser.getTeam()); 


        project = this.createInitialProjectContents(project);
        project = projectDAO.createProject(project);    
        currentUser.setTeam(teamDAO.updateTeam(currentUser.getTeam()));

        return "projects?faces-redirect=true";
    }    

    public void setCurrentContentForChapter(ProjectChapter chapter) {        
        currentContent = projectContentDAO.getProjectContentForProjectChapterId(chapter.getId());
        editorContent = currentContent.getContent();
        isEdit = false;
    }

    public void updateProjectContent() {

        editorContent = editorContent.replaceAll("\\r|\\n", "");
        currentContent.setContent(editorContent);

        currentContent = projectContentDAO.updateProjectContent(currentContent);
        isEdit = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: So it works using a plain `h:inputText` instead of a `pe:editor`?

Comment: additional hint: nested forms

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I don't see nested forms in my example. What do you exactly mean in regard to my code? So with h:input it's the same. I figured out, that the case was not on first page load or reload. Instead, when I update the column with id="currentChapters" via ajax, then the button is working only on second click. But I still can't figure out why? I've updated above code example with the whole page code.